# Extract dlls in Import Directory & runtime tool

Tags: windows, dll

I want to reuse a dll which is imported in another exe. Is there any tool that can extract dlls (load-time dynamic linking & run-time dynamic linking) of an exe?

[image: Load-time dynamic linking --> I want extract a copy of each dll (user32.dll, kernel32.dll ...)] Load-time dynamic linking --> I want extract a copy of each dll (user32.dll, kernel32.dll ...)

For run-time dynamic linking: I want to extract the dlls that are loaded via LoadLibrary functions.

Comment: Was this "another exe" already loaded before your application?

Comment: No, just this "another exe" not already run. I just want to analyze statically

Comment: What do you mean by "extract"? The DLL is stored as a resource in other executable?

Comment: Can you explain your situation in more details, what do you mean by "extracting a DLL"? It's name? Please edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your considering! After googling days by days for tools but didn't get any, I had my temporary solution that I write a tool as below:

- For load-time dynamic linking: Parsing the PE structure of this exe to export the dll names in the import directory then search them in %path% enviroment variable and the current directory of the exe. If the dlls exist, I copy them to the output.
- For run-time dynamic linking: Hooking the LoadLibrary functions to get the dll names then check the existence (similar as above).